# Regression analysis for more than one categorical variable in time series

Tags: regression, time-series, categorical-data

I have a time series data for shipment with following variables:

1. Year: 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013
2. Month: jan, feb, ..., dec
3. Number of ordering days
4. Shipment Volume

I want to know the effect of the number of ordering days on the shipment volume.

Can this can be done using regression method? If so, should I consider month and year as categorical variables?

Comment: You might want to look at the US Census Bureau's X13 software https://www.census.gov/srd/www/x13as/

Comment: You want to fit a time series model, which will take the correlation over months into account.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a time series approach to your analysis. Have the data as times series with monthly frequency. This will allow you to look at the variation in shipment volume due to the cycles and the actual effect of number of days.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer...Can explain it more...It would be great,

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an interesting problem.  You could take a look at this free [online book](http://istics.net/pdfs/multivariate.pdf) that I think is really good.

I think "example: births" on page 78 might give you some ideas for how to analyze your data.

Using different types of independent variable codings for (in the link's notation $\mathbf{x}$) in R is well described by [this page](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm)